# Is this an expression that makes sense? "These are all of my own tasks"

Tags: meaning-in-context

If I want to say to someone like "all of these tasks I've done only on my hands without the others",
then is this an expression that makes sense? "These are all of my own tasks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commonly, we would equivalently say "This is all my own **work**", for singular, or, "These are all my own work", for plural.

Yes, you can use "achievements" instead of "work", but then drop the "all" and the "own" from the above sentences.

That's not to say that your expression is incorrect, but it isn't as easily understood by native speakers of English as the equivalent expression provided above.

## TL;DR

It doesn't make *much* sense to use your particular expression.

Comment: But the task is not one. it's so many . then can I say These are all of my achive.

Comment: That's why I used *all*, and check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this work myself.

I've done this work on my own.

This is all my own work.

This is entirely my own work.

I did this all by myself.

I did this myself.

I did all of these things on my own.

I did all of this work myself.

I completed all of these tasks myself.